._startMicrotaskLoop crash on flutter app
I have been getting random crashes in my flutter app. This is the stacktrace that i am getting in firebase crashlytics. Not too helpful. Haven't found device or os commonality in crashes as well.
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: Null check operator used on a null value
       at ._startMicrotaskLoop(dart:async)

pool-23-thread-1:
       at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:341)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionNode.block(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:506)
       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.unmanagedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3466)
       at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:3437)
       at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1623)
       at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1071)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1131)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)



